# Stored procedure in Apache derby

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, derby

Can we create stored procedure with select, insert, update (multiple SQL statement) in apache derby database connection with Eclipse??

I am a beginner in android development, so please show me the proper way to create and use stored procedure.

Answer (score 7):

Just to clarify, these are not "stored procedures" in the classic sense that people familiar with Oracle and MS SQL Server would think of them.

Per the [link](http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/DerbySQLroutines) in @Bryan 's answer, as well as the thread [Regarding Derby Stored Procedures](http://apache-database.10148.n7.nabble.com/Regarding-Derby-Stored-Procedures-td82610.html), these "stored procedures" are *compiled Java code*, not SQL.  That's called [PSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL/PSM) and although googling for "Derby PSM" turns up some interesting results, it doesn't look fully-baked yet.

Comment: Looks like they could use some help.  The [feature request](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-5094) has been open since 2011 with no visible progress. At least there's also the start of a [design document](https://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/SqlPsmSupport) for it.

Answer (score 4):

Apache Derby certainly has stored procedures. Start here for some good information: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/DerbySQLroutines

I'm not sure about the "android development" part, though.

Answer (score 2):

It is absolutely possible to create a stored procedure in Derby.
To do so, you:

1. Craft stored procedure logic using the Java programming language
2. Package and deploy the Java logic to Derby
3. Create a stored procedure that wraps / calls the Java logic.
4. Call the stored procedure using JDBC.

This [post](http://carminedimascio.com/2013/07/java-stored-procedures-with-derby/) provides a step by step walkthrough describing exactly how to perform the above 4 steps.